# Why is this typescript program never ending?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, jwt

I have written this login command (Login.ts) for oclif in typescript. It is supposed to get some info in the login command of the cli, then create a token with jwt and write it in a file.

```
import Command from '@oclif/command'
import axios from 'axios'
import {flags} from  '@oclif/command'
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;
export class LoginCommand extends Command {
  static flags = { 
    user: flags.string({dependsOn:['passw']}),
    //email: flags.string({dependsOn:['passw'],exlucsive:['user']}),
    passw: flags.string()
  }

  async run() {
        const {flags} = this.parse(LoginCommand); 
        var mysql=require('mysql')
        var connection=mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            password: 'Vangelis98!',
            database: 'vag'
        });
        await connection.query(`SELECT user,pass,email,quotas FROM users WHERE user=?`,[`${flags.user}`], function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(`${flags.user}`);
                console.log(result[0].pass);
                const password=result[0].pass;
                if(bcrypt.compareSync(`${flags.passw}`, password)) {
                    var fs=require('fs');
                    var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('private.key');
                    var jwt=require('jsonwebtoken');
                    var token = jwt.sign({user:`${flags.user}`,passw:`${flags.passw}`}, privateKey, { algorithm: 'RS256' });
                    fs.writeFileSync("temptoken.txt",token);
                } else {
                    console.log("Wrong username or password\n");
                }       
         });

  }
}
```

I am running the command file like this:

```
energy Login --user afro --passw whatever12
```

And it runs correctly, but it never terminates, why? how can I fix this?

Comment: using await with a callback looks a bit funky to me. await helps with promises, but I don't think it works with the callback pattern like that. Maybe try removing `async` an `await` from your code and try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that the database [connection is not closed](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#introduction) and therefore the program does not terminate.